# Replacing a column in CSV file with another in bash

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a csv file with a number of columns. I am trying to replace the second column with the second to last column from the same file.
For example, if I have a file, sample.csv

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
a,b,c,d,e,f
g,h,i,j,k,l
```

I want to output:

```
1,5,3,4,5,6
a,e,c,d,e,f
g,k,i,j,k,l
```

Can anyone help me with this task? Also note that I will be discarding the last two columns afterwards with the cut function so I am open to separating the csv file to begin with so that I can replace the column in one csv file with another column from another csv file. Whichever is easier to implement. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 11):

How about this simpler awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2=$(NF-1)}'1 sample.csv
```

**EDIT:** Noticed that you also want to discard last 2 columns. Use this awk one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2=$(NF-1); NF=NF-2}'1 sample.csv
```

Comment: @JS웃 Coming from you, its a big compliment :)

Comment: Hi,when i use this command, it does what I want it to when I look at the file with excel, however when I open up the file on a notepad, the last field from a row has no separation from the first field in the next row. For example, if the last field from the first row is "apple" and the first field on the second row is "banana", after the command, i get "applebanana" I was wondering how i can combat this. Thanks

Comment: Opening in Notepad is a different problem than modifying CSV file. Notepad needs `\r\n` at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

In bash

```
while IFS=, read -r -a arr; do
  arr[1]="${arr[4]}";  
  printf -v output "%s," "${arr[@]}"; 
  printf "%s\n" "${output%,}"; 
done < sample.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution, using `IFS` in a funny way:

```
# Set globally the IFS, you'll see it's funny
IFS=,
while read -ra a; do
    a[1]=${a[@]: -2:1}
    echo "${a[*]}"
done < file.csv
```

Setting globally the `IFS` variable is used twice: once in the `read` statement so that each field is split according to a coma and in the line `echo "${a[*]}"` where `"${a[*]}"` will expand to the fields of the array `a` separated by `IFS`... which is a coma!

Another special thing: you mentionned the *second to last field*, and that's exactly what `${a[@]: -2:1}` will expand to (mind the space between `:` and `-2`), so that you don't have to count your number of fields.

*Caveat.* csv files need a special csv parser that is difficult to implement. This answer (and I guess all the other answers that will not use a genuine csv parser) might break if a field contains a coma, e.g.,

```
    1,2,3,4,"a field, with a coma",5
```

---

If you want to discard the last two columns, don't use `cut`, but this instead:

```
IFS=,
while read -ra a; do
    ((${#a[@]}<2)) || continue # skip if array has less than two fields
    a[1]=${a[@]: -2:1}
    echo "${a[*]::${#a[@]}-2}"
done < file.csv
```